# Digi ConnectPort Database adapter

Tags: python, database, pysqlite

I have a [Digi ConnectPort X4](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-routers-gateways/routing-gateways/connectportx4#overview) here and I am going to run a simple web server on it to serve the information from the ZigBee network that is attached.

The HTTPBaseServer and subclasses are pure Python classes, but I also want to have some kind of database running on the device. As I don't need to have complex functionality, I thought I would try to get PySQLite running on this embedded box.

However, as it turns out, I cannot use GCC on this box, so is there any other possibiliy to get some kind of database functionality on this box? Or did I miss a possibility to get that SQLite adapter on this box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone must have had a compiler to make Python.  A compiler is required to get (py)sqlite working.

You may be able to use the db/anydbm module instead which will use a flavour of dbm or a pure Python alternative. This won't give you a SQL database, but will give you a key value store which is likely good enough for your needs.

Comment: Yes, I can ask the manufacturer if it is possible to compile code for this specific box; however I think they may want to protect intellectual property.

I want to be able to store tuples of consisting of a timestamp, ZigBee Device Object ID, and some reals (power, current, THD, voltage etc). The key-value system feels like a simple array to me. Although this can be very powerful for simple applications, my application may need to store 104.000 records/tuples for a single device when > 50 devices may be needed in the future.

Comment: I see that there is the Shelve class which uses the anydb system with Marshal or Pickle to serialize the data to a string. However, this means my overhead my become quite large. Another thing is that Shelve also is not available 'out-of-the-box'...

Comment: Shelve is however fully Python and therefore I was able to run the shelf example. I think I may be able to work with this for the moment! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same situation as you. You can make yourself a pseudo DB with some tuples, or in my case some dictionarys. Something like that:

pseudoDB={}

pseudoDB[1]={'id':1, 'zb-dev-object':ZB_object, 'power':power_value}  #and so on

Comment: I was keeping that in another python file (.py) (pringing it just like a dictionary) and in some time when my ConnectPort X4 get restarted, that file is imported like module. This means you have to care for any INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE in DB terms.

Comment: I've ended up doing something similar, but I can derive the column information just from the index as that works more efficiently. Eventually, I just took my losses and did not write all values to disk directly, just every two minutes or so. File I/O has a lot of overhead. As for reading data; that's still very slow, but isn't done so often, could be easily improved although that would require another custom solution.